# Override global search results

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

Is it possible to override global search results in Salesforce? My app integrates with 3rd party services and I would like to search into these platforms from globals search bar.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to what you're asking for would probably be to use an [External Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_external_objects.htm), if that route is available for you. You would use [DataSource.Connection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_DataSource_Connection.htm) and [DataSource.Provider](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_DataSource_Provider.htm) to implement an integration with a third party system, then that data will appear as records in Salesforce that can be searched, queried, and so on. You'll want to start at [this page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.salesforce_connect_apex.htm&type=5) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. I think this approach requires access to external object in customer org, which adds to the pricing. I also don't want Salesforce to index and sync external data but just use my API(which in turn calls search API of external system. Might have to go browser extension route

Comment: @vishesh browser extension seems like overkill, and might not even be forward compatible every release. That said, I did look up the price for External Objects, and it's really expensive. I would have thought it'd be more reasonable.

Comment: I guess I will just have to post it on ideaexchange for now? Is it possible that if I have my LWC on the page, I can use javascript to access the page DOM and hack something?

Comment: can customer sidebar components be used here as advised in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25565850/salesforce-is-it-possible-to-override-salesforce-global-search

Comment: @vishesh That is pre-Lightning. It no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

There are third party tools like Coveo that provide source indexing capabilities and provide search experience. So you can index Salesforce and external sources. I don’t think you can override global search, but coveo search engine can be exposed as tab. In experience cloud, it does allow you to override external search engine. Maybe with data cloud, we may have these capabilities directly in Salesforce in future(e.g. https://www.salesforce.com/news/press-releases/2023/12/14/unstructured-data-ai-search-einstein/).